# Enforce Validation at the Model Level

Tags: dart

I have a model class and find myself enforcing validation rules in multiple places: when initially creating the object via a form, when allowing the object to be edited in another form, when manipulating the object within a function, etc.

In the end, the only real "validation rule" is me knowing in my head it needs to be done. If I forget to enforce it somewhere, future access to that object may cause a runtime error elsewhere.

I'm wondering how can I get as close as possible to the base model to enforce a validation rule (even if I redundantly enforce again later).

The two solutions I can think of are using an assert and/or throwing. Do other or better solutions exist? Can I get an error before runtime?

(Note: I'm assuming one approach will be to eventually write tests, but I haven't learned this skillset yet.)

Example:

Rule - "If the object's ExampleEnum is single, the list of integers must contain one but no more than one integer. If the object's ExampleEnum is multiple, the list of integers must contain at least one integer."

```
enum ExampleEnum { single, multiple }

class Foo {
  Foo({
    this.fooList = [1,2,3];
    this.fooEnum = exampleEnum.multiple;
  })

//BRAINSTORMED SOLUTION: 
 : assert (fooEnum == ExampleEnum.multiple && fooList.length != 1) || (fooEnum == ExampleEnum.single && fooList.isEmpty, 'NO!',);

  final List<int> fooList;
  final ExampleEnum fooEnum;

Foo copyWith({
  List<int>? fooList,
  ExampleEnum? fooEnum,
}) {

//BRAINSTORMED SOLUTION:
  if (fooEnum == ExampleEnum.multiple && fooList.length != 1) || (fooEnum == ExampleEnum.single && fooList.isEmpty) {
  throw 'NO!';
}
 return Foo(
  fooList: fooList ?? this.fooList,
  fooEnum: fooEnum ?? this.fooEnum,
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple ways to model it.

### Split it into multiple classes

My preferred way would be to create two completely independent classes. Objects with a single item and with multiple items seem to be independent. I'd split those up i.e. in `MultipleFoo` and `SingleFoo`. Both could implement the same interface, like an `Img` and `Video` which are both DOM elements.
You can read more about this when you search for "domain driven design"

You could create a union type using [freezed](https://pub.dev/packages/freezed#unionssealed-classes)

### Verify correctness in the constructor

To stay closer on your code, checking for correctness in the constructor is a good idea. You can prevent code duplication by calling the constructor again in your `copyWith` method.

```dart
void main() {
  Foo.multiple([1, 2]);
  Foo.single(1);
}

enum ExampleEnum { single, multiple }

class Foo {
  /// Private constructor, users should use factory constructors that prevent errors
  Foo._({
    this.fooList = const [1, 2, 3],
    required this.fooEnum,
  }) {
    // The constructor is a good spot to validate the correctness of the object
    if (fooEnum == ExampleEnum.multiple && fooList.length == 1) {
      throw "multiple items have to set fooEnum to ExampleEnum.multiple";
    }
    if (fooEnum == ExampleEnum.single && fooList.isEmpty) {
      throw "single items required ExampleEnum.single";
    }
  }

  /// Using factory constructors makes sure the object can't
  /// be created in an invalid state
  factory Foo.multiple(List<int> items) {
    return Foo._(
      fooList: items,
      fooEnum: ExampleEnum.multiple,
    );
  }

  factory Foo.single(int item) {
    return Foo._(
      fooList: [item],
      fooEnum: ExampleEnum.single,
    );
  }

  final List<int> fooList;
  final ExampleEnum fooEnum;

  Foo copyWith({
    List<int>? fooList,
    ExampleEnum? fooEnum,
  }) {
    /// will crash in constructor for invalid configured object
    return Foo._(
      fooList: fooList ?? this.fooList,
      fooEnum: fooEnum ?? this.fooEnum,
    );
  }
}
```